# How to add null values for all columns for missing dates and time in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with user name, dates, time of day and value associated for every hour.
I want to add missing dates for each user for all times of the day with null valued for values.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, do you want the dates to be default null until something is added?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I really hope you are not storing all that in the same table. Read about database normalisation.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  Also tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can add default constraint for date and give default value as null

Comment: I have a dataset containing names, dates and values for each date for the particular name. I have to insert missing dates for each user and then add 0 in the value column for that date

Answer (score 0):

when u created the  set it null

```
create table tablename
(
 colname as datetime null
)
```

this will set bydefault its value to null